# Sailsjs+AngularJS How to get data from query?

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I using Sails API and AngularJS.
I just wrote a factory like this.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .factory('Users', Users);

    Users.$inject = ["$resource"];
    function Users($resource){
        return $resource('Users/:id', {id: '@id'});
    };

})();
```

and in my controller perform

```
$scope.fabrics = Users.query({"level":"Fabric"});
```

it works!
But when i try to get 1 record using query

```
Users.query({"code":prod.fabric}).then(function(res){
        $scope.ddd = res.data;
      });
```

a get error, that then

```
.query(...).then is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add `$promise` like this:

```
Users.query({ "code": prod.fabric }).$promise.then(function (res) {
  $scope.ddd = res.data;
});
```